# Excel - complex if function

Tags: excel, excel-2010

I need help with my Excel table.
I want to compare my Reifenstärke with Reifenstärke, and than compare it with the weather to get the specific round number for that Car.

I need to use a IF-function but i don't really know how,

I will add a picture of my problem

https://www.dropbox.com/sh/7vstay1p15m15y1/AAAF5QHrj4Mf098tpd1I8gIda?dl=0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following `VLOOKUP` formula under "Minuten pro Runde":

```
=IF($E26=2,VLOOKUP($F26,$D$17:$I$19,6,FALSE),IF($E26=1,VLOOKUP($F26,$D$17:$I$19,5,FALSE),""))
```

Then copy it down as far as you need.